# Jodit Editor textarea text not wrapping

Tags: word-wrap, rich-text-editor, jodit

Jodit Editor (3.4.x.x) - Kubuntu 20.04, Firefox 83, Chrome/Chromium 87

When typing text into a textarea and the end of the Jodit editor width is reached, the editor does not wrap the text. Instead it keeps adding the characters onto the end and the horiz scroll bar turn on.

Is there a particular setting to enable this? I saw the 'wraptextnodes' plugin manages this and it appears this should be enabled by default.

The online examples work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me aswell. I believe it is about formatting the input.
Are you pasting content directly into the editor? If so, the html may be interfering with jodit.